# Whong php-config, right php -v and phpize

Tags: php, php7

This is okay

```
phpize

PHP Api Version:         20170718
Zend Module Api No:      20170718
Zend Extension Api No:   320170718
```

This is also okay

```
php -v

PHP 7.2.34-18+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 (cli)
```

This is not okay

```
php-config --version

7.3.27-9+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1
```

Everywhere I read says "just install php7.2-dev" but thats already installed.

```
php7.2-dev is already the newest version (7.2.34-18+ubuntu18.04.1+deb.sury.org+1).
```

So obviously the question is, how do I get php-config to match phpize and php -v

Answer (score 0):

You need to uninstall the `php7.3-dev` package. Alternatively, use versioned `php-config` (e.g. pass `php7.2-config` to `./configure`).